# new user - need pediatric data for various vitals parameters

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

I'm new to physionet and am attempting to dig/find a data set for various vitals parameters for a 48 hour period for a pediatric patient (say somewhere between 2-18), specifically heart rate, respiratory rate, temp, mean arterial blood pressure, and O2 saturate percentage.  I'm interested in a data set with fidelity along the lines of maybe a data point of once a minute... possibly every 30 seconds.  I'm open to any data fidelity that is available, but the 1 or 2 data points a minute would be ideal.  Can anyone provide me with guidance for how to gain access to a data set like this within physionet?